# header-location redirect doesn't work on web server

Tags: php, http-headers, http-post, http-redirect

I'm trying to use

```
header("Location: index.php")
```

in my login-script, but it doesn't work on my live-server, only local. I have no idea why there should be any problem.

I made some test also:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// header('Location: test.php');

require_once 'class/functions.php';
$func = new Functions();
//$error = "";
if(isset($_POST['loginSubmitted'])) {
    $user = $func->loginUser($_POST);
    if($user == true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        header("Location: index.php");
        die('test');
    }
    else {
        $error = 'Login nicht erfolgreich.';
    }
}
```

The "test" of die() function is shown, so it seems the header isn't even sent.

(And no, there is no output before the header function)

**Edit 3:**

Using get instead of post works. I'm really confused.

**Edit 2:**

I made a minified version for testing and even the following doesn't work. Seems like a server problem (in combination with $_POST?!):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    header('Location: index2.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="senden" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Updated the code example.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is nothing output before the header?  This includes any whitespace in your PHP file which would be translated to whitespace in HTML.

Comment: I am sure, because on local machine it works and if i provocate any output with echo before, i get also the "headers are allready sent" error.

Comment: var_dump(headers_sent()); To see if there is any kind of headers being sent.

Comment: Different servers react in different ways, my localhost never complains about output before headers.  However it seems that it may be a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some output being sent before trying to set a new header. Headers must all be set before any actual output is sent.

PHP will trigger a warning if you try this, but your error reporting settings may be blocking it. Set them to maximum temporarily to see where the output is being sent:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


echo 'Output!';

header('X-Test: Test');
```

Produces:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /test.php:6) in /test.php on line 8
```

Comment: Nope. Got the error, when i put an echo before the header-function.

Comment: @movsky Can you set any other headers? Try setting an X-Something header to test. Your host may have somehow disabled setting Location headers, or headers in general.

Comment: ehm, yes, it works when i put it on top of the file. this is really strange.

Comment: @movsky I'm not sure which header you meant works, but if you're still having troubles, the easiest way to diagnose where the problem lies is to make a new, empty file `redirect.php`, with nothing but `<?php header('Location: index.php');` in it, and see if that works. If it doesn't, the problem is with your host/your PHP config, if it _does_ work, then the problem is somewhere in your app

Comment: I updated the code in my start post. The redirect to test.php works, but the one to index.php doesn't. I got no error or anything.

Comment: @movsky If the first one works, and the second doesn't, then the problem is _somewhere_ within your app. Something is causing the problem, and it'd be almost impossible to tell what without going through all the files! One thing to try though is commenting out the `session_start()` line, since that's also dealing with headers, and see what that does. And maybe replace `die()` with `exit()`, just to be absolutely sure that the problem isn't in that file.

Comment: I found out that the redirect doesn't work when it is in the if(isset($_POST))-Part. (I deleted all the other lines in there). On any other place it works... Well, thanks for your help to get there. :)

Comment: Seems a like a problem of webserver in combination with $_POST. Have no clue why.